# matplotlib boxplot xticks shifting towards y axis

Tags: python, numpy, pandas, matplotlib

I am beginner to matplotlib and trying to plot a boxplot for my data I extracted using pandas.

I am successful in getting boxplot which looks perfectly like what i want except xtics. These xtics are getting shifted towards yaxis. I dont know why.

Here are my example arrays:

```
In [74]: print occ

[[0.40000000000000002, 25.199999999999999, 2.0, 0.40000000000000002, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0], [0.0, 21.199999999999999, 0.0, 0.0, 26.800000000000001, 12.800000000000001, 0.40000000000000002, 0.40000000000000002, 0.40000000000000002, 0.0], [0.0, 31.199999999999999, 0.0, 0.0, 21.600000000000001, 0.0, 0.0, 0.40000000000000002, 0.0, 4.7999999999999998], [0.0, 32.0, 0.0, 0.0, 23.199999999999999, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0], [0.0, 37.350000000000001, 0.0, 0.0, 13.65, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 1.2]]

In [78]: dfAll.pair
​
Out[78]:
0    GLU18-Side-ASN50-Side
1    ASN50-Side-ARG21-Side
2    GLN14-Side-ASN42-Side
3    ASN42-Side-GLN14-Side
4    GLN14-Side-ARG43-Side
5    SER46-Side-ARG15-Side
6    ASN42-Side-ARG15-Side
7    GLU11-Side-ASN42-Side
8    ALA39-Main-GLN14-Side
9    GLU18-Side-SER46-Side
Name: pair, dtype: object
```

And below is my matplotlib boxplot code:

```
plt.boxplot(np.array(occ),  showmeans=True, whis="range", showbox=True, labels=dfAll.pair)
plt.xticks(range(0,(dfAll.pair.shape[0])), dfAll.pair, rotation='vertical')
plt.show()
```

[image: Box Plot Image with xticks shifted towards y axis.]

Any idea why this is happening, and how to get proper xtics?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The error lies in this line:

```
plt.xticks(range(0,(dfAll.pair.shape[0])), dfAll.pair, rotation='vertical')
```

The fact that you're explicitely specifying `0` as the starting point is causing the problem. Change it to:

```
plt.xticks(range(1,(dfAll.pair.shape[0]+1)), dfAll.pair, rotation='vertical')
```

Just as a side note, since you have values at `y=0` I would extend the `ylim()` to maybe `-5`

Comment: This solves my problem partially. With the first xtick at the right position the last box is still without tic.
Trying something based on your answer.

Comment: Thanks. I also got that.
Added my own answer. Then deleted after seeing you comment. Thanks.